# Find user in mongo, with mongoose, and return the result to a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to search in mongo some user and put them in a json, but everytime I tried it the result that I got is a big object with metadata.

The following code contains what I've done

```js
var myJson = {
              user : User.findOne({
                        firstName: regex,
                        lastName: authorSplitedName.last
                     }, function (err, user){
                        return user;
                     })
             }
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: You receive the result in the **asynchronous** callback function. In case you're using express, you typically do something like `res.json(user)` in your function (instead of the current `return user`). `User.findOne` will **not** return your result.

Comment: Thank you, although now i will use $or, to search multiples results and pass then to a callback

Comment: Not sure whether this was a question :) but: The same applies if you search for a collection; the difference is, that your callback method will receive an array as second parameter instead of a single object.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to remove mongoose object property:

```
var myJson = {
              user : User.findOne({
                        firstName: regex,
                        lastName: authorSplitedName.last
                     }, function (err, user){
                        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)));
                     })
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose's `find` methods return their results **asynchronously** via the callback function. This means, the `findOne` method will **not** give you the query's result (as obviously assumed in your sample code). In case you're using express.js, you typically do something like `res.json(result)` in your callback function to send the JSON result:

```
router.get('/:someParameter', function(req, res, next) {
    var query = {}; // your query
    User.findOne(query, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err); // handle error case
        res.json(user);
    });
});
```

If you need a raw JSON or raw Object without any mongoose-specific properties, you can use the [`toJSON()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON) or [`toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject) methods on mongoose documents.

Concerning your comment; not sure whether this was a question, but: The same applies if you search for a collection; the difference is, that your callback method will receive an array as second parameter instead of a single object.