# How to get data with default type from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I'm setting up a new server with nodejs connect to mongodb using mongoose. When I use `model.find()`, it returns data but not default json type in mongodb

```
User.find({}, (err, docs) => {
  if (err) {
    res.send({
      status: false,
      message: err
    })
  } else if (docs) {

    res.json(docs);
  } else {
    res.send({
      status: false
    })
  }
})
```

This is what I get

```
{
  "_id": "5c25b0dc44eb7569f240e13c",
  "username": "",
  "idScores": [
    "5c1e100a44eb7569f240e118",
    "5c1e104744eb7569f240e11a"
  ]
}
```

But I want this result

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "507c35dd8fada716c89d0013"
  },
  "username": "",
  "idScores": [{
      "$oid": "5c1e100a44eb7569f240e118"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "5c1e104744eb7569f240e11a"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Maybe this could help you, if you haven't checked the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054622/find-user-in-mongo-with-mongoose-and-return-the-result-to-a-json) already?

Comment: @ShreyaShah thank you for your reply but I found it has no help to me. I can get JSON from response data but I want reference fields always include $oid at each id :)

Comment: Is decoding json and then adding the `$oid` then encoding it back can be an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strict MongoDB Extended JSON for alias ObjectId() -> $oid
 [read more](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#oid)

1) JSON can only represent a subset of the types supported by BSON.

2) To preserve type information, MongoDB adds the following extensions to the JSON format.

3) The representation used for the various data types depends on the context in which the JSON is parsed.

```
{"_id": {"$oid":"507c35dd8fada716c89d0013"})
// is same as
{"_id": "507c35dd8fada716c89d0013"}
```

You don't need to add "$oid" in every _id element it is just notation. You can access it using dot _id